# Let user in AD set date/time by hand

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

Under a 2012 AD, as usual, users cannot set date/time on their computers as this is managed by organization. For specific  purposes, we need to let one of the users set date to past but options are greyed out. Through GPO we have granted permission to change date/time and timezone to that user. Policies are updated and seem correct as rsop.msc for that user shows that directive is correctly enabled... But no luck,still greyed-out option to change time by hand.

Is there any directive I am missing to allow this?

EDIT: Managed to set time through classical  control panel but it reverts back to NTP after a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For specific purposes, we need to let one of the users set date to past but options are greyed out.

No, you ***don't*** need to do this is on an AD joined computer.

AD (Kerberos) *relies* on the time being synchronized to within a few minutes. If not, things like login, file shares, TLS and a slew of other functions that needs time will stop working.

You should look into a different solution - perhaps a virtual machine that is not AD joined, or even a separate computer - but you should *not* **ever** set time on AD joined computers manually.

---

The impracticality of it aside: I would attempt to change the workflow to not require setting time. Such requirements typically stems from X-Y problems.

Comment: I know, I know. In fact I had increased kerberos time from 5 to 99999 minutes. But your proposed virtual machine solution seems right to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should probably not increase the kerberos time. There's a reason time is part of the authentication protocol. By removing it you're undermining the security of the protocol.